# class.method in R S4

Tags: r, class, oop

I recently finished to set up my objects in R using the S4. But I still have a giant doubt. Right now when I have to call a method I call it as below:

```
ClassObject <- method(ClassObject, other parameters)
```

My question is: how do I set up the methods in order to call them in the following way:

```
result <- ClassObject.method(other parameters)
```

Is it even possible in S4? I know in S3 it is, but I don't really like the way of creating classes in S3.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Not sure it is possible for S4. As an aside have you looked at R6 classes. They combine the more stringent approach used by S4 classes but with some of the flexibility of S3 methods, i.e. not needing to specifically specify the class when calling a method (because the method is self contained withing the initiated R6 object).

Comment: @MorganBall Thank you for your prompt answer, I actually didn't check for the R6 classes. I'll take a look at it now! Thank you again.